# How can I use python code to automate download

Tags: python-3.x

how to use python to open each URL present in a text file to open in IDM "add URL corner" (or chrome if not allowed in IDM) and start downloading it also it has to wait for the time till download finishes and start downloading next file (in short automating download process by python on IDM or chrome)

[image]

I scrape the website and stored all file link in text file now how can I pass all the link in IDM one by one

```
    import io
    from selenium import webdriver
    chrome_path = r"C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start 
    Menu\Programs\Python 3.7\chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



   with open('downloads_urls.txt','w') as f:
   f.write('')

   index = 1 
   driver.get('http://s11.bitdl.ir/PC.Game/Battlefield.1.CorePack/')
    urls = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//tr')
    with io.open('downloads_urls.txt','a') as f:
    for i in urls.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@href]'):
    print (i.get_attribute('href'))
    f.write(i.get_attribute('href')+"\n")
    index = index+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need IDM or chrome.

Use [requests](https://2.python-requests.org//en/master/) instead.

```
In [1]: import requests                                                                                  

In [2]: r = requests.get('http://s11.bitdl.ir/PC.Game/Battlefield.1.CorePack/')                          
Out[2]: <Response [200]>

In [3]: import re

In [4]: re.findall(r'<a href="(.*?)" title="\1"', r.text)                                               
Out[4]: 
['Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part01.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part02.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part03.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part04.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part05.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part06.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part07.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part08.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part09.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part10.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part11.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part12.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part13.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part14.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part15.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part16.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part17.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part18.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part19.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part20.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part21.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part22.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part23.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part24.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part25.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part26.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part27.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part28.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part29.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part30.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part31.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part32.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part33.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part34.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part35.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part36.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part37.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part38.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part39.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part40.rar',
 'Battlefield.1-CorePack.V0.bitdownload.ir.part41.rar']
```

You can also use `requests.get` to download the rar files.
But then, instead of using `r.text`, use `r.content` to get the binary file contents.

Something like:

```
import requests
import re

base = 'http://s11.bitdl.ir/PC.Game/Battlefield.1.CorePack/'
r = requests.get(base)

files = re.findall(r'<a href="(.*?)" title="\1"', r.text)

for f in files:
    fr = requests.get(base + f)
    print(f'Starting download of {f}.')
    with open(f, 'wb') as binfile:
        binfile.write(fr.content)
    print(f'Downloading {f} finished.')
```

Comment: I tried above steps but i don't understand what is happening after binfile.write(fr.content) also where the file is downloading

Comment: After the file contents are written, the file is closed because I used a *context manager* (in the form of `with`). After all the files are wrtten, the program exits. Since `open` uses just a filename, the file is written to the current working directory. Use `os.chdir()` to change the working directory, or preped a output path to `f` in the `open` call.

Comment: how can i monitor downloading

Comment: @prince See updated answer. If you want to do more fine-grained monitoring you could e.g. use `aiohttp`. See e.g. [this example](https://www.terriblecode.com/blog/asynchronous-http-requests-in-python/).